# Flutter stripe payments getway

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add stripe payment gateway to my flutter app but it doesn't work .
there is any way to do that without working with nodejs ?

Comment: Hi @NordineEnn, Welcome in SO, Please try to add more info in your question to get the proper response here..Like what have you tried to achieve this task..Add your code with question also ..Thanks

Comment: i just tried call  stripe api using  https  request

Comment: Hi there, no unfortunately there is no way to integrate Stripe into your flutter application without some server-side portion (e.g., nodejs). A server-side portion is necessary to process all payments on Stripe, with the one exception being client-only checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client. It isn't clear from your question what isn't working with your integration - but, if you post another question with more detail someone might be able to help.

Comment: hey thanks . i tried to do some api https calls and its working for me . i can create customer and add card and create payment and confirm or cancel it . so i think thats all

Comment: That's great, glad to hear it!

Comment: but im still confused , why people use backend and why nodejs exaclty .